# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:?

Tags: java

```
import  javax.swing.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int r=0,c=0;

String input,inputt;
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Plz Enter the number of Rows");
r = Integer.parseInt(input);

 input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Plz Enter the number of Coloms");
c = Integer.parseInt(input);

int array[][]= new int[r][c];
for (int i=0;i<=r;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<=c;j++)
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Plz Enter the elemet of the array");
        array [r][c]= Integer.parseInt(input);
    }


}
```

I'm trying to declare 2d array using JOption

Answer (score 8):

You are running off the end of the 2D array with your `for` loop conditions:

```
for (int i=0;i<=r;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<=c;j++)
```

Valid indexes are `0` through `r - 1` and `0` through `c - 1`, so you went one too far with each.  Try

```
for (int i=0;i < r;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j < c;j++)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few mistakes in your code

1. you never check what user give as input (what if it is lets say "one")
2. your loops will include `r` and `c` in `i` and `j` range where there max index for them is `r-1` and `c-1`
3. in `for (int j=0;j<c;j++)` reading and converting users data need to be done in code block, or loop will execute only reading `c` times
4. in your loop you are using fixed indexes `array [r][c]` instead of `array [i][j]`.

Comment: @user2970213 Take a look at my point 3. Your code is currently asking user `c` times for input, and when `j==c` (which stops your second loop) it is trying to place it at `array[0][j]` which in this case will be `array[0][c]`.

Comment: @user2970213 to correct it inside your loops put your `input .. Integer.parseInt(input)` inside `{  }`.